# Unbale to identity WinForm ListView subitems in Coded UI test VSTS 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

This is my window application code for listview :-

```
// Create three items and three sets of subitems for each item.
        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("item1", 0);
        item1.SubItems.Add("1");
        item1.SubItems.Add("2");
        item1.SubItems.Add("3");
        ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("item2", 1);
        item2.SubItems.Add("4");
        item2.SubItems.Add("5");
        item2.SubItems.Add("6");
        ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("item3", 0);
        // Place a check mark next to the item.
        item3.Checked = true;
        item3.SubItems.Add("7");
        item3.SubItems.Add("8");
        item3.SubItems.Add("9");

        // Create columns for the items and subitems.
        // Width of -2 indicates auto-size.
        listView1.Columns.Add("Item Column", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Column 2", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Column 3", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Column 4", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);

        //Add the items to the ListView.
        listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1, item2, item3 });
```

Then i add the lisview control in Coded UI test  :-

In the coded UI test i used below code

```
WinList wkList = this.UIForm1Window.UIListView1Window.UIListView1List;

            string[] strVal = CommonExtensions.GetValuesOfControls(wkList.Items);

            foreach(WinControl control in this.UIForm1Window.UIListView1Window.UIListView1List.Items)
            {

                int count = control.GetChildren().Count;
                object objVal = CommonExtensions.GetValue(control);
                WinListItem lstItem = (WinListItem)objVal;
            }

in the "strVal " variable gives only values of first column not the subitems.

in add watch window i get below mentioned value:-

strVal[0] = "item1"
strVal[1] = "item2"
strVal[2] = "item3"
```

I have also used the http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/2010/02/19/useful-set-of-utility-functions-for-coded-ui-test.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

```
WinListItem listItem = new WinListItem(control);
string[] strSubItems = WinExtensions.GetColumnValues(listItem);
```

In the above statement i am getting Invalid Io expection stating "The control passed is not a list view item control.  This operation is valid only for list view item control."

Please suggest any other alternative ?.

Comment: It looks like you are just hoping that some random code you downloaded from the Internet is going to do your job.  That rarely works in practice.  Just get rid of it and write your *own* code.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use smth like that:

```
WinList list;

UITestControlCollection columns = websitesList.Columns; // Get Columns names

// Get values
foreach (WinControl item in list.Items)
   {
        WinListItem listItem = new WinListItem(item);
        string[] subItems = WinExtensions.GetColumnValues(listItem); // So you get value = subitem[i] in column[i]
   }
```